# Firebase Only one Client Update Node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

user Firebase game for web/javascript and one thing that mystifies me is how to only have ONE client update a node. I'm keeping track of the game's state by adding the name of the state and a timestamp to a node. When that child node is added, all the clients react to the game state change event.

Works great but I only want to have one client do the database update so I basically choose the first person in the room. That's bad though because they might be offline or something. How do I tell the clients to only run the following operation once?

```
var newstate = this.gamestateURL.push();
newstate.set({state:"player"+nextplayernum,timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

Thanks so much! Frank if you see this I appreciate your help!

Comment: Since this is the same code as [your question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021876/firebase-clear-node-contents), is the problem any different? Please don't post the same problem multiple times, but *edit* the original question to be clearer.

Comment: It's a different question entirely.

Comment: From the question you asked yesterday - "How can I clear the node contents and add the next player change **without the event getting fired twice?**" and from this question - "How do I tell the clients to only **run the following operation once?**" You are just asking the same question over and over again.

Comment: My first question was how do I clear the contents and add new data without the clients receiving listener events for both the clear and the addition of new data.

Comment: The other question (which I'm much more curious about) is the best way to essentially have one client act as a dealer in a game of cards. I need to change the turn to the next player by updating a node in the database but not have all clients do it. If I've got five people playing a game and it's time to move to the next player I don't want 5 clients setting the gamestate to "player2". Apologies for confusion.

Comment: I'm currently having player 1 update the gamestate but what if that client stops running because the user moves to a different tab in their browser and gameplay cannot continue because player 1 isn't updating the state??? Trying to wrap my head around doing this in a serverless environment.